# How to make a message box appear when too many/or too little characters are entered

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hey so I'm relatively new to python and am creating a Memory Game for a school project. The way I've set it out is that the user chooses a difficulty, then characters show up (6 random characters), then an enter character screen shows up. I'd like to implement a message box that appears if the user enters more than 6 characters, or less than 6, stopping them from progressing to either the correct or incorrect screen.

```
class EnterCharacterScreen(tk.Frame):  

 def __init__(self, parent, controller):  
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="#2699C3")  
    self.controller = controller  

    lbl1 = tk.Label(self, text=" ", fg="white", bg="#2699C3")  
    lbl1.pack() 
    lbl2 = tk.Label(self, text=" ", fg="white", bg="#2699C3")  
    lbl2.pack()  
    lbl3 = tk.Label(self, text=" ", fg="white", bg="#2699C3")  
    lbl3.pack()  
    lbl4 = tk.Label(self, text=" ", fg="white", bg="#2699C3")  
    lbl4.pack()  
    lbl5 = tk.Label(self, text=" ", fg="white", bg="#2699C3")  
    lbl5.pack()  
    label = tk.Label(self, text="What were your characters?", font=controller.title_font, bg="#2699C3")

    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)  

    def get_answer():  
        if entry_characters.get() == word:  
            controller.show_frame("CorrectScreen")  
        else:
            controller.show_frame("IncorrectScreen")  

    def get_answer2(event):  
        if entry_characters.get() == word:  
            controller.show_frame("CorrectScreen")  
        else:
            controller.show_frame("IncorrectScreen")  

    global entry_characters  
    entry_characters = tk.Entry(self, justify="center")  
    entry_characters.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=10)  
    entry_characters.config(font=("Courier", 96))  
    entry_characters.bind("<Return>", get_answer2)  
    global button_submit  
    button_submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=get_answer, height=4, width=20)  
    button_submit.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=10)  
    button_submit.config(font=("System", 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you link the entry box to a tkinter StringVar, you can trace the entry box's contents and use a function to check the length of the contents. See effbot's docs here:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

You can use the tkinter TopLevel widget to create a message box, or you could just disable the submit button if the user hasn't entered six characters.